# React Native cli project - debug in vscode

Tags: react-native, debugging, visual-studio-code

How to catch breakpoints in vscode in React Native cli project?

**Background:**
Few days ago I started learning react native.
I was able to catch breakpoints in vscode in my expo projects. With some settings but still.
But when I started new cli project I lost this comfort.

**Notes:**

- **Debug** is activated on virtual android machine
- **react native tools**
  package is installed
- **Attach to packager** as the default debug
  configuration (During launch.json creation I was missing „React
  native“ environment option. Do not know why.)

I run my apps normally with two commands

```
npm start
npx react-native run-android
```

Thank you for your time.